# Finding number in list of tuple

Tags: python

Suppose a function`get_number(directory, person)`, which returns the person's phone number. If the number is not found, return `0`.

```
def make_directory():
    return []

def add_number(directory, person, number):
    directory.append((person,number))
    print(str(person) + ' ' +'added!')
    return(directory)


def get_number(directory, person):
    if person == directory[0][0]:
        return directory[0][1]
    elif len(directory) >= 1:
        return get_number(directory[1:],person)
    else:
        return 0


phonebook = make_directory()
add_number(phonebook, 'Police', 999)
add_number(phonebook, 'Lynna', 8444)
add_number(phonebook, 'Jack', 1123)
add_number(phonebook, 'Sister', 5720)
print(get_number(phonebook, 'Jack')) # I should be getting 1123
print_list(phonebook) #[('Police', 999), ('Lynna', 8444), ('Jack', 1123), ('Sister', 5720)]
```

But I am not able to get it. May I know what is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Because, you are comparing the name against the number. What you should have is

```
if person == directory[0][0]:
```

Also, the condition should if the `directory` has enough values in it first. So, the conditions will become like this

```
if len(directory) >= 1:
    return 0
elif person == directory[0][1]:
    return directory[0][1]
else:
    return get_number(directory[1:], person)
```

**Note:** I would recommend using a Python dictionary here. They are there for this very purpose.